# Xiaomi Fingerprint

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, fingerprint-reader

I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on the Xiaomi Notebook Ari 13'3 but I couldn't get the fingerprint function running for logon. The Fingerprint GUI sees no device at all. Maybe there are necessary drivers for the Xiaomi Fingerprint sensor?

Here's the output (partial) of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5a3 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the `lsusb` command. This should enumerate the fingerprint reader device,  which will help us better troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @richbl the result is
_Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5a3 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub_

Comment: @MetaColon, I edited your question to make the output of `lsusb` more legible.

Comment: @richbl As a matter of fact, it's not my question, I just have the same problem.

Comment: The key to what `lsusb` tells us is that the fingerprint device is from Elan Microelectronics Corp (device 04f3:0c1a). We can use that information to better troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: It actually seems to be a known issue for a similiar device: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290

Comment: @Eugen, some additional information about your device: no native support through the original [`libfprint` project](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Supported_devices/).  However, there's [a very recent project up on GitHub that's doing some work directly related to the Elan fingerprint sensors](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint). In fact, there's [a recent request for support of your specific device noted here](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint/issues). I'd suggest you contact the developer, let them know you have the device, and offer to help out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71234/discussion-between-metacolon-and-richbl).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue solved by installing fingerprint+gui package. 
After adding this package Ubuntu recognised the fingerprint HW.

Add ppa source:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
```

Update source list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Installing this packages will overwrite/remove default package "policykit-gnome" In case you decide to remove this PPA, reinstall default policykit.

Comment: helped through different versions of Ubuntu togather with 17.10

Comment: did this work for a xiaomi laptop? Tried this on mine without luck.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: The installation did work, but the interface showed the message "No Devices Found". Did you test it with the device 04f3:0c1a from Elan Microelectronics Corp?